# How to freeze a variable value in an Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

Given this Ansible playbook:

```yaml
- name: CI/CD management, via cidre.io
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local

  vars:
    cidre_version: "{{ lookup('file', '../VERSION') | default('v0.1.0') }}"

  roles:
  - role1
  - role2
```

I understand everytime I use `cidre_version` variable, Ansible read `VERSION` file, hence value is dynamic and can change across tasks.

How can I freeze this value when playbook starts?

Comment: Unrelated: `lookup('file', '../VERSION') | default('v0.1.0')` will fire an error when file does not exists. `lookup('file', '../VERSION', errors='ignore')` will return an empty string in such cases. Then `default('v0.1.0', true)` will return the default value for empty and null values as well as undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@vijesh answer is correct. Meanwhile, it is possible

1. to override the var value statically keeping the same name
2. to play that `set_fact` tasks before roles so you can use the value everywhere. You simply have to put it in the `pre_tasks` section.

Note: I fixed your initial var definition so it will work in case the version file does not exist.

```yaml
---
- name: CI/CD management, via cidre.io
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local

  vars:
    cidre_version: "{{ lookup('file', '../VERSION', errors='ignore') | default('v0.1.0', true) }}"

  pre_tasks:
    - name: Fix the value of version and override playbook definition
      set_fact:
        cidre_version: "{{ cidre_version }}"

  roles:
    - role1
    - role2
```

Comment: this works like a charm! I would have thought of a syntax like Ansible did with ``!unsafe`` , something like ``!static`` but, pre_tasks do the trick, thanks you.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to do that inside the role "role1" ? to avoid copy/paste

Comment: `set_fact` will have the same position in [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#ansible-variable-precedence) weather you play it in your playbook or in a role. So I don't see why it would not work.

Comment: I think I just got entirely your question: you can probably define your 'dynamic' value in `vars/main.yml` and then `set_fact` in `tasks/main.yml`. That's worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

Nice question.

You can do the following:

1. Create a task in which you copy that file if exists otherwise you create a new file adding the default value.
2. Initialize the variable reading from this new file.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: this looks too complicated, I am sure there is a special keyword for that

Answer (score 1):

You may use `set_fact` at the start of the playbook to store the value of `cidre_version`. Something like:

```
- name: CI/CD management, via cidre.io
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local

  vars:
    cidre_version: "{{ lookup('file', '../VERSION') | default('v0.1.0') }}"

  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      cidre_version_static: "{{ cidre_version }}"

  - name: remaining tasks...
```

Comment: I tried this, I use also ``roles`` and look like role taks are executed before playbook tasks.

Comment: Have you tried the ```set_fact``` inside roles? And still the value is changing?

Comment: @ThomasDecaux that is absolutely right, and this is why there are also `pre_tasks` you can use in your playbook that will fire before roles: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles-at-the-play-level